# Runtime control population using XML in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A thought came in mind, is there any way to populate control in runtime using XML. I mean I will have one Controls.xml file and in that file I can define what control i want to add to a perticular winform and when we run that app it will show exact controls. Has anyone done this? Please guide me on this.

Comment: This type of thing will require you to store a lot of parameters about your controls inside your XML file, including things such as positioning, tab indicies, event handlers, etc. I'm having a hard time imaginging a scenario in which the added complexity of pulling from a form is the better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Serialize a Control (which is an Object) to XML than Deserialize se [HOW TO](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2517/serialize-and-deserialize-objects-to-an-xml-file/)

But the issue would be Event's ,where you should use Reflection and/or Code Injection into the Application because Event's cannot get Deserialized as an Object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create the controls dynamically: all you need to do is to parse the XML and then create them.

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Location = new Point(25,25);
tb.Click += textbox_Click;
this.Controls.Add (tb);
```

Comment: This I know but I want to read control information from XML file.

Comment: I thought you were persisting user selected controls by serialising to XML and then restoring at runtime.